# Designing a function in Python that verifies the following rules

Tags: python, function

I'm working on a problem that requires me to write a function in Python that checks 4 rules of a particular input. I keep getting errors when I run my code in Python, but I'm not sure why it's not working. Can someone please help?

Here is the input: input = "5000-0000-0000"

Here are the rules:

1. The first digit must be a 4.
2. The fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit; keep in mind that these
   are separated by a dash since the format is ####-####-####.
3. The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4.
4. If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eighth
   digits as a two-digit number, their sum must be 100.

Here is my code:

```
 def verify(number) : # do not change this line!

  length = len(input)
  first_number = int(number[0])
  is_4 = True
  for i in range(0, length):
    if int(number[0]) != 4:
      is_4 = False
      break
  is_one_higher = True
  for i in range(3, length):
    if int(number[3]) + 1 > int(number[5]):
      is_one_higher = False
      break
  count = 12
  sum_by_four = True
  sum = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[5]) + int(number[6])+ int(number[7]) + int(number[8]) + int(number[10]) + int(number[11]) + int(number[12]) + int(number[13])
  sum
  if sum % 4:
    sum_by_four = True
  Combo_1_and_Combo_2 = True
  combo_1 = int(number[0]) + int(number[1])
  combo_2 = int(number[6])+ int(number[7])
  if combo_1 + combo_2 == 100:
    Combo_1_and_Combo_2 = True
  elif combo_1 + combo_2 != 100:
    Combo_1_and_Combo_2 = False
 
  return verify(input) # modify this line as needed

input = "4037-6000-0000" # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
print(output) # prints the output of the function
# do not remove this line!
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error on line 32:
    output = verify(input) # invoke the method using a test input
Error on line 29:
    return verify(input) # modify this line as needed
Error on line 29:
    return verify(input) # modify this line as needed
Error on line 29:
    return verify(input) # modify this line as needed
  [Previous line repeated 986 more times]
Error on line 6:
    for i in range(0, length):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: After I format your spacing, I don't get an error so you'll have to be specific about what kind of error you're getting

Comment: Hi, I made an edit to the post. Please check now. Thank you.

Comment: `return verify(input)` is clearly wrong. This is leading to infinite recursion.

Comment: Why does the `verify` function call itself in its `return` statement? This is infinite recursion with no base case, which is precisely what the thrown exception states.

Comment: Further, why is the `verify` function accessing the global variable `input`? It should only use the parameter `number`. Also, `input` is a built-in function in Python, so you should refrain from using it as a variable name. In this case, it's hard to tell if your statement `return verify(input)` is passing the `input` function as an argument or the global `input` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code does the trick:

```
def verify(number):  # do not change this line!
    # no need to loop here
    first_number = int(number[0])
    if first_number == 4:
        is_4 = True
    else:
        is_4 = False
    print('is_4:', is_4)

    fourth_digit = int(number[3])
    fifth_digit = int(number[5])
    # your logic only checked if the fourth digit was greater than the fifth digit by 1
    # instead your code should check if the fourth digit is greater by EXACTLY 1
    if fourth_digit == fifth_digit + 1:
        one_greater = True
    else:
        one_greater = False
    print('one_greater:', one_greater)

    sum = int(number[0]) + int(number[1]) + int(number[2]) + int(number[3]) + int(number[5]) + int(number[6]) + int(number[7]) + int(number[8]) + int(number[10]) + int(number[11]) + int(number[12]) + int(number[13])
    # you have to check if the result of sum % 4 because the modulus operator will return the remainer of the division
    # for the total to be divisible by 4 there has to be no remainder
    if sum % 4 == 0:
        sum_by_four = True
    else:
        sum_by_four = False
    print('sum by four:', sum_by_four)

    # instead of converting each number[#] to an integer and then adding them together
    # first concantenate the two numbers as strings and then convert the 2 digit string to an integer
    combo_1 = int(number[0] + number[1])
    combo_2 = int(number[7] + number[8])
    if combo_1 + combo_2 == 100:
        Combo_1_and_Combo_2 = True
    elif combo_1 + combo_2 != 100:
        Combo_1_and_Combo_2 = False

    # check if all conditions are true or false and return the appropriate value
    if Combo_1_and_Combo_2 and sum_by_four and is_4 and one_greater:
        return True
    else:
        return False


input = "4207-6058-0000"  # change this as you test your function
output = verify(input)  # invoke the method using a test input
print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot. I appreciate you taking the time to explain. For a beginner like me this is extremely useful. Cheers.